# Is there a conventional notation or name for the slip angle?

Tags: aerodynamics, yaw

Angle of attack is usually designed by *alpha* (as in [alpha_prot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/what-is-the-alpha-protection)).

Is there such a conventional notation or name for other axes? I'm particularly interested in the slip angle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sideslip angle is commonly notated as β (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_(aerodynamics)).

Answer (score 7):

There is only one other such angle. It is indeed the sideslip one, and its standard greek letter is $\beta$ (beta)