# If a stall is at the same angle of attack what is the stall speed?

Tags: stall

So I of course know that the wing can stall at any angle of attack, but what then is the stall speed? Is that the speed at which the wing will always stall and it may stall at a higher speed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the immediate cause of stall?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/what-is-the-immediate-cause-of-stall)  This should give you everything you need.  Also [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-does-stall-depend-on-angle-of-attack-but-not-speed?rq=1).

Comment: The stall will occur after a certain angle of attack is reached (related to the airflow). If the pilot had to maintain a level flight while slowing down the aircraft, they would need to increase the angle of attack. At some speed this angle will be the stall angle, slowing down furthermore without descending will stall the wing. The speed corresponding to the stall angle, in level flight, is (abusively) named the stall speed. Note the stall will not occur at this speed if the aircraft is not flying level (but the angle of attack for the stall will remain the same).